# Tinyint field not being set

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set the value of a tinyint field to 1, 2, or 3, but it's not being set. I am pretty new at mySQL, so I am probably making a mistake somewhere, but I can't see it.

I called the function and all the other fields are being set, just not tinyint, which keeps showing as 0.

```
 $this->db->update('jobattachment', ['redline' => $tid], ['id' => $attachmentid], ['editing' => '2']);
```

I have tried removing the quotes around the 2 and also setting a variable and doing ['editing'] => $editingLevel, but nothing works.

Code for update:

```
public function update($table = '', $set = NULL, $where = NULL, $limit = NULL)
{
    // Combine any cached components with the current statements
    $this->_merge_cache();

    if ($set !== NULL)
    {
        $this->set($set);
    }

    if ($this->_validate_update($table) === FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ($where !== NULL)
    {
        $this->where($where);
    }

    if ( ! empty($limit))
    {
        $this->limit($limit);
    }

    $sql = $this->_update($this->qb_from[0], $this->qb_set);
    $this->_reset_write();
    return $this->query($sql);
}
```

This is the limit code:

```
public function limit($value, $offset = 0)
{
    is_null($value) OR $this->qb_limit = (int) $value;
    empty($offset) OR $this->qb_offset = (int) $offset;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Can you share `update`'s code?

Comment: I had it in my original question.  Did it not appear or do you want something else?

Comment: Nope, the only thing shared here is the way you call `update` - I was asking about the implementation of `update`. It's impossible to help you without seeing it.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I will post the code ASAP.

Comment: @RivaPortman After you have posted a [mcve], what is the SQL query you are building with the current arguments you have? What is the result or error you get from MySQL?

Comment: @Progman, thank you for your response. I don't know how, but I got it working. I wasn't getting an error, I just found that when I checked the value in the table, it was always 0.

Comment: Your `update()` function takes 4 parameters, the last of which is an optional `limit`.  When you call it, you are passing 4 parameters, but the last one is an array (`['editing' => '2']`).  You haven't shown us your `limit()` code, but I am assuming the value it expects an integer, not an array. So that suggests something is wrong with how you are passing parameters.  My guess is the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th params you are passing in are in fact meant to be 1 parameter, a single array, representing your `$set`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, thank you for your comment. I added the limit code, and, as you said, it expects an integer.

Comment: OK - I tried to elaborate on my comment in another comment but ran out of space. I summarised and posted it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `update()` function takes 4 parameters, the last of which is an optional limit. When you call it, you are passing 4 parameters, but the last one is an array (`['editing' => '2']`).  My guess is `$limit` is supposed to be an integer, so your code might generate something like `... LIMIT 5`.

So it looks like there is something wrong with how you are passing parameters.

Right now, here's how the variables are set up by the parameters passed to `update()`:

```
$table = jobattachment
$set   = ['redline' => $tid]
$where = ['id' => $attachmentid]
$limit = ['editing' => '2']
```

My guess is that all the last 3 are supposed to be in `$set` - you are passing in 3 column names, each with a new value to save.

Again, we can't see your actual `set()` code, but probably it expects an array of key/value pairs.  So you would call `update()` like this (re-formatted to make it clear that you are passing just 2 parameters, vs 4 previously)

```
$this->db->update('jobattachment', [
    ['redline' => $tid],
    ['id' => $attachmentid],
    ['editing' => '2']
]);
```

Now `$set` is a multi-dimensional array of data to save.